# How does one move the tick labels closer to the axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg, y=wt*1000, color = factor(cyl))) + geom_point() 
p + ylab("weight (lb)") +theme_bw()
```

[image: tick labels too close to vertical axis]

I would like to move 5000, 4000, 3000, and 2000 closer to the vertical axis. I know one can instead use `theme(axis.title.y=element_text(vjust=0.36,hjust=.36))` or similar to move the axis title further away, but sometimes I really want to move the tick labels, not the axis title.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Version `2.0.0` introduced the new `margin()` which we can use here:

```r
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = wt*1000, color = factor(cyl))) +
  geom_point() +
  ylab("weight (lb)") + 
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(margin = margin(r = 0)))
```

[image]

My reading of this [issue on github](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/1252) is, that you should use `vjust` only for the `y-axis` and `hjust` only for the `x-axis`. To alter the distance between tick-label and axis, use `margin(r = x)` on the y-axis, and `margin(t = x)` on the `x-axis`. Doc for `element_text` reads: "When creating a theme, the margins should be placed on the side of the text facing towards the center of the plot."

Answer (score 5):

One solution would be to use `axis.ticks.margin=` element of `theme()` and set it to 0. But this will influence both axis.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg, y=wt*1000, color = factor(cyl))) + geom_point()  + 
      ylab("weight (lb)") +theme_bw()+
      theme(axis.ticks.margin=unit(0,'cm'))
```

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't `axis.text.y` ("y axis tick labels"; from `?theme`) be useful as well?

Comment: @Henrik using `axis.text.y` I was able only to move labels verticaly (`vjust`) but `hjust` had no effect.

Comment: @Henrik there is a relatively new possibility with `axis.text.y`, see my answer.