How to set the Y and X values in the graph origin
I am trying to plot the following graph:

But the Y axis ticks are not close to the colors lines.
How can I make the rectangule complete the full background area?
This is my code:
plot1 <- ggplot(data = data, aes(x = X, y = Y)) +
  geom_point()+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0,40,80,120,200,400),limits = c(0,400),expand = c(0, 0))+ # Define the corresponding y-axis tick labels
  labs(x = "", y = "Y") +  # Adicione rótulos aos eixos, se necessário+
  theme_minimal()+
  theme(panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),  # Remove major grid lines for y-axis
        panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank())+# Remove minor grid lines for y-axis
  coord_cartesian(xlim = as.Date(c("2021-12-21", "2023-01-01"),ylim = c(0, 400)))  # Definir a origem do gráfico para junho de 2022
plot2 <- plot1 + annotate("rect", 
                          ymin = c(0,40,80,120,200),
                          ymax = c(40,80,120,200,400),
                          xmin = as.Date("2021-12-21"), xmax = as.Date("2022-12-30"), fill = c('green', "yellow","orange","red","purple"), alpha=0.5)

I've already tried to change the limits on xmin and xmax, but as the X axis is a DATE TYPE, it does not work. Also, I've tried to specify the Xaxis as -Inf and Inf, but also it did not worked since is a DATE TYPE.
I am expect to let my entire baground with color.
Sample Data

Hi, the sample data in that form is not helpful (I can't even read it). But is the basic question that you want to move the labels closer to the axis or is it that you want them inside the axis?

Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32836693/how-does-one-move-the-tick-labels-closer-to-the-axis

Hey Elin! The question that you sent me, it helped a lot! Thanks
But I wanted to move the labels closer to the axis

You should be able to use negative numbers.

Voted to close. It is unclear and most likely a dupe..

Please do not add data as an image for these reasons. This link has some really useful guidance regarding how to create an MRE, and how to share example data in particular. Thanks

Does this do what you want? If so, use scale_x_date(expand = c(0,0) instead of coord_cartesian(...).
library(tidyverse)

# Had to create an example dataset
set.seed(222)

data <- data.frame(
  X = seq(as.Date('2022-01-01'),
             as.Date('2022-12-31'),
             '1 day'),
  Y = rnorm(365, 200, 50)
)

# Here is a similar plot to the one posted 
plot1 <- ggplot(data = data, aes(x = X, y = Y)) +
  geom_point()+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0,40,80,120,200,400),limits = c(0,400),expand = c(0, 0))+ # Define the corresponding y-axis tick labels
  labs(x = "", y = "Y") +  # Adicione rótulos aos eixos, se necessário+
  theme_minimal()+
  theme(panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),  # Remove major grid lines for y-axis
        panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank())+# Remove minor grid lines for y-axis
  coord_cartesian(xlim = as.Date(c("2021-12-21", "2023-01-01"),ylim = c(0, 400)))  # Definir a origem do gráfico para junho de 2022

plot2 <- plot1 + annotate("rect", 
                          ymin = c(0,40,80,120,200),
                          ymax = c(40,80,120,200,400),
                          xmin = as.Date("2021-12-21"), xmax = as.Date("2022-12-30"), fill = c('green', "yellow","orange","red","purple"), alpha=0.5)

plot2


# Here is the updated plot using scale_x_date(expand = c(0,0) instead of coord_cartesian(...)
data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = X, y = Y)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0,40,80,120,200,400),
                     limits = c(0,400),
                     expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "2 month",
               date_labels = "%b %Y",
               expand = c(0,0)) +
  labs(x = "", y = "Y") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank()) +
  annotate("rect", 
           ymin = c(0,40,80,120,200),
           ymax = c(40,80,120,200,400),
           xmin = as.Date("2021-12-21"), xmax = as.Date("2022-12-30"), fill = c('green', "yellow","orange","red","purple"), alpha=0.5)


Created on 2024-05-14 with reprex v2.1.0
